# Mvc single page crud operation with you grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, user-interface, grid

I am trying to do single page application crud with uI grid but it give error on post

Comment: What kind of error your getting.

Comment: check u entered right url

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at link content, it can help you:

https://www.sitepoint.com/creating-crud-app-minutes-angulars-resource/